# Proxy to allow traffic only towards OpenVPN server

Tags: networking, server, vpn, proxy, openvpn

I use OpenVPN with proxy HTTP header for my VPN customers.
Everything works fine, but currently the proxy - which must remain unauthenticated - can be used outside the `.ovpn` config file, as an independent "free" proxy.

I need a way to force the HTTP proxy to allow traffic only towards the OpenVPN server (IP) that I own, so that only my OpenVPN customers can take advantage of that proxy.

Any working line I should add in `/etc/squid/squid.conf`?

**PS:**
The OpenVPN and the proxy are placed on the same server (`localhost`).
If this is a problem, I can use 2 different machines. No problem at all.